# Passing visual studio webtests fail in test explorer

Tags: visual-studio, testing, performance-testing, webtest, test-explorer

I have a web performance and load testing project which executes as epected when I open the test definition and hit run however fails when i run through test explorer.

I have narrowed this down to only tests which reference another project in the solution (utilities project for custom validators).

when running tests via test explorer it errors with `Request failed: Could not load file or assembly 'PerformanceTestingUtilities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` However works fine if I open the test and hit run.

What could be causing this to happen? I get no errors on build and nothing in the output.

Comment: The DLL containing the named assembly, or a DLL that it needs, is not available on the computer where the tests are being executed.

Comment: It's not running on a remote computer.
If I open the test and run on my device it passes but running through test explorer on my device fails with the above error

Comment: Sure, but it is as I said. I have used "Fuslogvw.exe" to debug such problems. See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/meason/2016/11/09/debugging-loadlibrary-failures/ and the pages it references.

Comment: Has your question been solved? If it has then can you write the solution in an answer?